# Adding spaces after each character in a string in python (the pythonic way)

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have a string as:

```
s = 'HelloStackOverflow'
```

What is the most *"pythonic"* way to convert it to:

```
'H e l l o S t a c k O v e r f l o w '
```

?

(space after last character is indifferent)

I could come up with:

```
s = ''.join(map(lambda ch: ch+' ', s))
```

But I suppose there is a more transparent way to do it

Comment: `' '.join(s)`-?

Comment: Do you actually want the trailing space?

Comment: No, I don't mind abou the trailing space. Either way is fine. (Was my sentence confusing? If so, please edit it to be more clear)

Comment: No, but your example very clearly includes a trailing space. Most times it's unwanted, so `' '.join(s)` fits the bill if you don't want a trailing space.

Comment: Simply searching Google for your *exact title* led me directly to the question I've marked as duplicate. Please do try and do *some* research before posting questions.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I did. The post you mentioned was about efficiency. My question is about writing in in the most compact way regardless of efficiency. Even though one of the answers is the same, the intend is clearly different, that's why I asked (And that's why it isnt exactly a duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code

```
' '.join(s)
Out[1]: 'H e l l o S t a c k O v e r f l o w'
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the OP's requirement of a trailing space.

Comment: I am not sure if it is actually needed. I guess we can add a whitespace after it manually with `+ ' '`

Comment: cast to `list` is not needed

Comment: Thanks, that seems elegant

Comment: @PaulPanzer Agree.

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` and replace each single character in the string by that captured character followed by a single space.

```
s = 'HelloStackOverflow'
print re.sub("(.)", r'\1 ', s)

H e l l o S t a c k O v e r f l o w
```

### Demo

Comment: Lovely, I'm not sure if it more transparent, but it sure is clever.

Comment: My `timeit` tests show that this is several times slower than `' '.join(s)` and functionally equivalent (except for the trailing space which the OP indicated he didn't really want/need), while much more complicated / non-obvious.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Should the OP's replacement requirements change even slightly, the accepted answer would fall short, while a regex based solution would be easily adaptable.  I'm not sure this answer merits a downvote.

Comment: I could write a C extension to ensure the utmost flexibility for any string manipulation operations the OP *may* require in the future. Certainly that would not be a good solution, right? Write code for your requirements, not perceived future needs when [you aren't gonna need it](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). More complex, less efficient; I saw this in a code review, I would kick it back immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
' '.join(s)+' '
```

For the exact behavior you wanted.